# ListView with ViewHolder, TextViews change content

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a custom `CursorAdapter`. In there I have this:

```
if (Main.distance_unit.equals(Main.miValue)) {
                //[...] some code here which converts units

                holder.mi.setText(mileageResult + " " + Main.distance_unit);
            } else if (Main.distance_unit.equals(Main.km)) {
                holder.mi.append(" " + Main.distance_unit);
            }
```

now the problem is, when I first open the `ListView` Fragment, everything is fine, but when scrolling down and up again, the units disappear. Am I right thinking this is caused by the `ViewHolder`? How can I fix this?

[image: Before scrolling]

[image: After scrolling]

The Whole Code, probably a few stupid lines of code in there. You're welcome to suggest a better way of doing these things:

```
public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        super(context, R.layout.activity_db_row, c, from, to);

        mCursor = c;
        ctx = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getView(position, v, parent);
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (v == null) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_db_row, parent, false);
            //noinspection deprecation
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

            DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
            decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
            decimalFormatGal.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

            holder.price = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_tprice_unit);
            holder.price.setText(Main.money_unit);

            holder.lprice = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_lprice_unit);
            holder.lprice.setText(Main.money_unit + "/" + Main.amount_unit);

            holder.amount_unit = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_amount_unit);
            if (Main.amount_unit.equals(Main.galValueImp)) {
                holder.amount_unit.setText(Main.galValue);
            } else holder.amount_unit.setText(Main.amount_unit);

            bindView(v, ctx, mCursor);

            holder.am = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_amount);
            String amount = holder.am.getText().toString();
            holder.am.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormatGal.format(Double.parseDouble(amount))));

            holder.mi = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_mileage);
            String mileage = holder.mi.getText().toString();

            holder.tp = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_tprice);
            String tprice = holder.tp.getText().toString();
            holder.tp.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(tprice))));

            holder.lp = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_lprice);

            holder.d = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_date);

            holder.fuel = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_fueltype);
            String fueltype = holder.fuel.getText().toString();

            if(fueltype.equals("null") || fueltype.length() == 0) {
                holder.fuel.setText("");

                //ToDo: Remove at some point
            }

            String amountResult;
            if (Main.amount_unit.equals(Main.galValue)) {
                BigDecimal amountTmp, toGal, resultTmp;
                double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(amount);
                amountTmp = BigDecimal.valueOf(amountDouble);
                toGal = BigDecimal.valueOf(DbAdapter.toGal);

                resultTmp = amountTmp.multiply(toGal).setScale(2,
                        RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                amountResult = resultTmp.toString();

                holder.am.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(amountResult))));

            }

            if (Main.amount_unit.equals(Main.galValueImp)) {
                BigDecimal amountTmp, toImpGal, resultTmp;
                double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(amount);
                amountTmp = BigDecimal.valueOf(amountDouble);
                toImpGal = BigDecimal.valueOf(DbAdapter.toImpGal);

                resultTmp = amountTmp.multiply(toImpGal).setScale(2,
                        RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                amountResult = resultTmp.toString();

                holder.am.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(amountResult))));

            }

            if (Main.distance_unit.equals(Main.miValue)) {
                BigDecimal mileageTmp, toMi, resultTmp;

                double mileageDouble = Double.parseDouble(mileage);
                mileageTmp = BigDecimal.valueOf(mileageDouble);
                toMi = BigDecimal.valueOf(DbAdapter.toMi);

                resultTmp = mileageTmp.multiply(toMi).setScale(2,
                        RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                String mileageResult = resultTmp.toString();

                holder.mi.setText(mileageResult + " " + Main.distance_unit);
            } else if (Main.distance_unit.equals(Main.km)) {
                holder.mi.append(" " + Main.distance_unit);
            }



            v.setTag(holder);
        } else holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        return v;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        RobotoTextView price;
        RobotoTextView lprice;
        RobotoTextView amount_unit;
        RobotoTextView am;
        RobotoTextView mi;
        RobotoTextView tp;
        RobotoTextView lp;
        RobotoTextView d;
        RobotoTextView fuel;
    }
```

Comment: it is may be bcoz listview recycles views

Comment: please post complete method for us to debug

Comment: Whole code of 'MyCusorAdapter' is in the question. Thanks
@Raghunandan yeah i kinda mentioned this in the question. not sure how to fix this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See sample pattern here:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    if (v == null) {
        /* inflate your view if "v" is null */
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_db_row, parent, false);            

        /* hold the reference of your view through ViewHolder */
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.price = (RobotoTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_tprice_unit);

        ......

       /* set view tag */
       v.setTag(holder);
    }

   /* This is where you should update your view state values */
   ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

   DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
   dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
   decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

   holder.price.setText(Main.money_unit); 

   ..... update view's 
  return v;
```

}

What happens on your example code snippet was. On first iteration of the listview. You code snipper works fine
because the view was basically has not yet been recycled. And on your issue. it's were the view get recycled.
causing from if (v == null) will not be executed because the view maybe already recycled. Thats why your view
state properties are not updated.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i begin to understand how the `ViewHolder` works.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `new ViewHolder()` every time. You need to create a new instance if `convertView` is null. If `convertView` is not null, then get the holder. In either case, you need to set the values to the view. You are using the pattern wrong. Please look at sample code below that explains how to use a view holder properly:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    /*
     * The convertView argument is essentially a "ScrapView" as described is Lucas post 
     * http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/
     * It will have a non-null value when ListView is asking you recycle the row layout. 
     * So, when convertView is not null, you should simply update its contents instead of inflating a new row layout.
     */
    if(convertView==null){

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

        // store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // object item based on the position
    ObjectItem objectItem = data[position];

    // assign values if the object is not null
    if(objectItem != null) {
        // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
        viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(objectItem.itemName);
        viewHolder.textViewItem.setTag(objectItem.itemId);
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

Credits/Source: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html